# Why it can't get total row?

Tags: vb6

I am using VB6 I want to get total row first to be an reference in next step by using Do Unitel end of file for twice.

## first Do

for get total row from the file

## second Do

for loop value to display but system skip scond Do

Please see my code

```
   Dim FileNumber As Integer = FreeFile()
    Dim FirstLine As Boolean = True
    Dim rownum As Int32 = 0
    Dim Totalrow As Int32 = 0
    Dim MinY As Double = 999999
    Dim MaxY As Double = -999999
    Dim DiffY As Double = 0
    Dim currentval As Double = 0
    Try
        FileOpen(FileNumber, XMFileName, OpenMode.Input)
        Do Until EOF(FileNumber)
            Dim Text As String = LineInput(FileNumber)
            Dim _val = Text.Split(vbTab)
            Totalrow += 1
        Loop

        Do Until EOF(FileNumber)
            Dim Text As String = LineInput(FileNumber)
            Dim _val = Text.Split(vbTab)
            rownum += 1
            If FirstLine Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To Text.Length - 1
                Next
                FirstLine = False
            Else
                If rownum >= 364 And rownum <= 695 Then
                    currentval = CDbl(_val(1).ToString())
                    If MinY > currentval Then
                        MinY = currentval
                    End If
                End If

                If rownum >= 696 And rownum <= Totalrow - 4 Then
                    currentval = CDbl(_val(1).ToString())
                    If MaxY < currentval Then
                        MaxY = currentval
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Loop

        If MinY = 999999 Or MaxY = -999999 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Program can't read QC file at row" & rownum.ToString() & ", Please manual check the data.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Exit Sub
            'Else
            DiffY = MaxY - MinY
            'MessageBox.Show(Math.Round(DiffY, 5))
            Dim lvitem As ListViewItem
            lvitem = Me.uiListView.Items.Add(MinY)
            lvitem.SubItems.Add(MaxY)
            lvitem.SubItems.Add(Math.Round(DiffY, 5))
            For Each lvi As ListViewItem In Me.uiListView.Items
                lvi.UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
                lvi.SubItems(2).ForeColor = Color.Yellow
                lvi.SubItems(2).Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("QC measurement error at row :  " & rownum.ToString() & ". QC file less than condition. It must be more than 193 rows." & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Exit Sub
    Finally
        FileClose(FileNumber)
    End Try
```

Is there any other way to get the total row for reference?

Much thanks friends.

Comment: This looks like VB.NET to me.  Please correct your tags.

Comment: Is it VB6 or VB.net?

Answer (score 1):

The eof condition of the second loop is true when it begins as it is also the end condition of the first loop, so this second loop cannot be performed at all.

Close and reopen the file between your two loops to correct that problem.